# Arquilian fails to inject UserTransaction with multiple deployments

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

I have this class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class myIT {
    @Inject
    private UserTransaction utx;

    @Resource(mappedName="java:/jdbc/myDS")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Deployment(name="DeployOne", order = 1)
    public static Archive<?> deployOne() throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Build and return the file
    }

    // @Deployment(name="DeployTwo", order = 2)
    public static Archive<?> deployTwo() throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Build an empty file return the file
        return = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "deployTwo.war");
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        //Do things with utx
    }
}
```

As you can see, deployment 2 is commented, so my deployment works fine.
If I uncomment the @Deployment annotation, utx is not injected anymore and I get a null pointer exception.

Am I missing something? Why adding a new deployment causes my UserTransaction not to be injected anymore?

Comment: Is the datasource also null in your setup method? Do you have a beans.xml in those deployments?

Comment: You might have to tell arquillian in which deployment context your setup and test methods should run, using `@OperateOnDeployment("DeployTwo")`. See [Blog Post](http://arquillian.org/blog/tags/examples/). Maybe that works, haven't tried it. BTW: usually you inject a `UserTransaction` with `@Resource` instead of `@Inject`.

Comment: @jabu.10245 That did the tricker, thanks :) (I've corrected the UserTransaction injection). Can you please change it to an answer so I can mark it as such,please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject the `UserTransaction` as a resource, since it's managed outside the CDI container.

```
private @Resource UserTransaction transaction;
```

See this [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgli.html).